# How to run a php script asynchronously in Windows?

Tags: php, command-line

I am using xampp, in Windows 7.

in my understanding, calling a script this way should run the php.exe asynchronously and not wait for the script to end.

```
$run_cmd = "cmd c:/xampp/php/php.exe c:/xampp/htdocs/Gashash/batch_test.php";
$oExec = $WshShell->Run($run_cmd, 0, false);
```

of course:

```
$run_cmd = "cmd c:/xampp/php/php.exe c:/xampp/htdocs/Gashash/batch_test.php";
exec($run_cmd);
```

the exec() option doesn't work as desired as it halts the calling process until *`batch_test.php`* ends.

I tried using '\' and '\' as well as '/' for the slashes in the path but the script doesn't work!

Any suggestions ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ii have answered this 3 times in the last week, please search first.

```
$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$run_cmd = "cmd c:/xampp/php/php.exe c:/xampp/htdocs/Gashash/batch_test.php";
$WshShell = $WshShell->Run($run_cmd, 0, false);
```

Comment: I did see your answer, but still. No go... I copied paste it right now.

Comment: what happens? as that's the 'universal' answer i have never had any problems with.

Comment: well, if I change the Run's 0 param to 1 I get the cmd line show up and immediately close. My batch_test.php script should be writing something to the log as a test. But the log is empty. If I execute the same line through cmd manually (without cmd as the beginning) it runs ok, if I add the cmd it doesn't

Comment: Something in the script was weird. I changed the log write to a COM wscript.shell calling to notepad.exe, and it executed it. Sorry for the bother